# Typescript and redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

How can I make an array of Recipe type in Initialvalue, and how to make Payloadaction as a object type? I am a typescript beginner unfortunetly.

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type Recipe = {
    title: string, 

}

const INITIAL_VALUE = {
    recipes: []
}


const recipeSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'recipe',
    initialState: INITIAL_VALUE,
    reducers: {
        addRecipe(state, action: PayloadAction<{}>) {
            state.recipes.push(action.payload)
        }
    }
    
})
```

Answer (score 3):

`[]` will be an array of `never` since there isn't any information about the type of an element in the array. The simplest thing you could do is assert `[]` to be `Recipe[]`

```
const INITIAL_VALUE = {
    recipes: [] as Recipe[]
}


const recipeSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'recipe',
    initialState: INITIAL_VALUE,
    reducers: {
        addRecipe(state, action: PayloadAction<Recipe>) {
            state.recipes.push(action.payload)
        }
    }
    
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=3&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZQDbDJoA0cAChgJ54QYAmAgsjMBAHZwC+cAZlBCDgAiAALo6AVwAeAKwDOAehgQIeANbAYQgNwAoXTEpg0cAEppkwY3AC8iXXEdwWMPGgBccOTCjA2Ac1J9Tn1kdm84AEkAOUiAFUiGABkAfQA1ZIBVAFFbeyc4dEtjOU8AbQBdOAw5MwsrNErdENDw+CKG-EITO1RMbC6iAAoEByc2DBAPOAByDuMZ4jHHP01gDDwcGCxpmPjE1IyknKWC8QkiKFL8gqd6OnNitCHvHdIMZlY2TwpqWkZPuwADyPBoAPgAlDdbrdXtgAHTzNByeFgCRyAAWQw+LHYqKoNHoEOWtxCBTJTmaEKAA)

You could also provide an explicit type annotation for `INITIAL_VALUE` but that will require you do it for all properties and will require you define the properties in two places:

```
const INITIAL_VALUE: {
    recipes: Recipe[]
} = {
    recipes: []
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZQDbDJoA0cAChgJ54QYAmAgsjMBAHZwC+cAZlBCDgAiAALo6AVwAeAKwDOAehgQIeANbAYQgNwAoXTEpg0cAEppkwY3AC8iXXEdwWMPGgBccOTCjA2Ac1J9Tn1kdm84AEkAOUiAFUiGABkAfQA1ZIBVAFFPBAcndEtjOU9zYrQAbQBdXW47fKc4Iqs0Urgauv1dMLYIluN8QhM7VExsIaIACkanNgwQDzgAcgG0ZeICxz9NYAw8HBgsJZj4xNSMpJzNpvEJIih22abHejpy1qnvY9IMZlY2J4KNRaIx-uwADwfYwAPgAlPYXkivEdsAA6NZyNFgCRyAAWUz+LHY2KoNHocK2LxCTRpTjqcKAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried on my own but I modified INITIAL_VALUE using bad practice like const INITIAL_VALUE: {
    recipes: Recipe[]
} = {
    recipes: []
    
}. Once again thanks for a cleaner solution